PostgreSQL getResultStream() vs getResultList()
I have a query to retrieve all rows in a table:
@Repository
public class ARepository {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  public List<A> findAll() {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<A> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);
    Root<A> root = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);

    criteriaQuery.select(root);

    return entityManager
        .createQuery(criteriaQuery)
        .getResultList();
  }

}

I'd like to use Stream to prevent memory overloading:
@Repository
public class ARepository {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  public Stream<A> streamAll() {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<A> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);
    Root<A> root = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);

    criteriaQuery.select(root);

    return entityManager
        .createQuery(criteriaQuery)
        .getResultStream();
  }

}

However, I don't really understand the difference between getResultList and getResultStream, given that documentation states: "Execute a SELECT query and return the query results as a typed java.util.stream.Stream. By default this method delegates to getResultList().stream(), however persistence provider may choose to override this method to provide additional capabilities". If this is the case (I'm using PostgreSQL), what's the point of using one or the other? How can I prevent running out of memory then?

Hibernate has implemented it differently. So streaming will use a cursor and retrieve the rows one by one. However if you still stuff them in a list or collect them otherwise you gain nothing as in the end everything is still in memory.

@M.Deinum how do you know Hibernate has implemented differently? I can't find that information anywhere

Check the hibernate sources, use a debugger etc.

if you want to read a large amount of data without running out of memory, you should also use a stateless session in order to disable hibernate first level cache.
